# How can I compile bits of text into lines of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to produce a line of code that looks something like this:

```
search.condition1(ape).condition2(monkey).condition3(gorilla)
```

This is for using it in a construction such as:

```
jungle(search.condition1(ape).condition2(monkey).condition3(gorilla))
```

The problem is that I want only the conditions that have been set (at least one will always be set) to be included in the string. I set these through user `input`. So, let's say I have received:

```
cond1 =
cond2 = giraffe
cond3 = zebra
```

In that case, the line of code should be:

```
search.condition2(giraffe).condition3(zebra)
```

That is, excluding the `condition1` altogether.

I have tried this solution:

```
searchstring = "search."

if len(cond1) > 1:
    searchstring += "condition1(cond1)
else: pass

if len(cond2) > 1:
    searchstring += ".condition(cond2)"
else: pass

if len(cond3) > 1:
    searchstring += ".condition(cond3)"
else:pass
```

This correctly compiles, through string appending, what I want, but does so -- obviously -- as a `string`.

So, when I write ...

```
jungle(searchstring)
```

... that does not achieve the same thing as if it had been raw code, so to speak. It is not executable.

Any ideas for solutions, or better practices?

Comment: BTW, `else:pass` is entirely superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to *construct code*. You want to modify your queryset as needed.

E.g.:

```
conditions = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

query = search

for term in conditions:
    query = query.condition(term)

jungle(query)
```

This is equivalent to `search.condition('foo').condition('bar')...`. You're calling the `.condition()` method on the return value of the previous `condition()`, and are using the final result as argument to `jungle()`.

If you somehow need to call different methods instead of always the same `condition()` (which isn't entirely clear from your question), you'll need to figure out what the logic is there and then simply do:

```
query = getattr(query, 'name_of_method_to_call')(term)
```

Construct the "`'name_of_method_to_call'`" as needed dynamically.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the name of the method is different from time to time. My real-life case is to construct a twitter search to look something like this: `tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setUsername("barackobama").setSince("2015-09-10").setUntil("2016-01-01").setMaxTweets(1).setEmoji("unicode")`. I get the feeling that the whole thing must be passed as one, which would make your iterative method unsuitable. No?

Comment: Well, same idea. Instead of a `for` loop you'll have some `if ...: query = query.setUsername(...)` then. And depending on what library you use, you may not even need the `query =` part. Just doing `if ...: query.setUsername(...)` will probably suffice.